# Cache Tiles to avoid blank space when zooming-out in OpenLayers3 example

Tags: animation, caching, zooming, openlayers-3, bounce

Among the OpenLayers3 animation examples is this one: [OpenLayers3 Animation Example](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch03-charting-the-map-class/example-04.html) in which you "bounce to Rome" and "Fly to Paris" etc.  When the map zooms out there is blank space around the edges which I interpret as lack of caching.  It is very noticable on a full screen map.  Is there a way to enable caching of the Tiles? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a lack of caching. The reason for the blank is that your map starts showing regions that have not previously been loaded when you zoom out for the first time. If you go back to the original extent and then zoom out again, you'll see that there won't be blank spaces because the tiles are already cached.